# Error: Process completed with exit code 254. and table wont load

Tags: javascript, node.js, github-actions

I am trying to build a site using GitHub Actions. This is the workflow that is trowing an error:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run script
        run: node script.js
```

Error:

```
Run npm ci
  npm ci
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/GiBillOverseas/GiBillOverseas/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/work/GiBillOverseas/GiBillOverseas/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2024-02-22T20_05_45_180Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 254.
```

I have no idea where to even start.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/AlexMcVay/GiBillOverseas

Comment: Have you tried running a more recent version of node? The latest stable build is [21.6.2](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current).

Comment: There's no `package.json` in your repo that's what the [error](https://github.com/AlexMcVay/GiBillOverseas/actions/runs/8010337067/job/21881081040#step:4:9) is about and that's why `npm ci` command is failing. You need to push your `package.json` to your repo. Also, `node script.js` command won't work as `script.js` is under the `site` directory. You need to switch directory first i.e. `cd site`. Use the same steps in your workflow that work for you locally.